# Check the openGL version on OSX

Tags: objective-c, macos, opengl

I'm looking for a trick that display on my OSX application the OpenGL version in my Mac.

I add the GLUT and GL framework but I haven't found anything for check the version.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I haven't found anything for check the version.

[`glGetString()`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glGet.xml) with `GL_VERSION`.

Make sure you have a current GL context before you call that.

Comment: Well, I have call glGetString() without a context. Thanks

Comment: Can you please explain steps in detail. (e.g. Open Terminal / Xcode etc).

Comment: so to clarify, glGetString(GL_VERSION) is a command from OpenGL that returns your OpenGL version.  You should run it on your c++ application, but you need to create an OpenGL Context. In short, a context represents an instance of OpenGL running. Usually an instance is created by creating a window. So if you have an OpenGL application that shows up a window, you might have a function called glutCreateWindow, and it will work if you call the glGetString() after this.